# Firebase rules write fails while read succeeds

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have these rules in my real-time database and cannot figure out why only the .write rule fails, while the .read succeeds. Both the write rule and read rule are the same aside from ".write" and ".read" so if one works, shouldn't the other?

In the 'Users' node all users have a homesteadId value which I'm trying to make sure is == to the uid under the Homesteads node which they are trying to edit.

```
"Homesteads": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "root.child('Users').child('auth.uid').child('homesteadId').val() == $uid"
    ,".read": "root.child('Users').child('auth.uid').child('homesteadId').val() == $uid"
  }
}
```

The highlighted nodes in the image below are the ones I'm trying to compare to ensure they are equal in order to give read/write access to the user.

[image: Database screenshot]

I've also noticed that loading the data in my app has slowed down as a result of the above read rule. Now when the user signs in the data doesn't show immediately in its recyclerview as it should, and requires closing the app and opening it again before the data is displayed (or navigating to another view in the app and returning). Do security rules like this affect database query performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `child('auth.uid')` in your rules with `child(auth.uid)` (without the quotes. Right now you're passing in a literal string, where instead you want to pass in the *value* of the variable.

Comment: On your other question: if the data is properly indexed, query performance should be fine unless you have hundreds of thousands of nodes. If you don't have the right indexes on your data, you will get a warning in your logcat output saying so. If so, read the documentation on indexing data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is a good oportunity for me to check if I have it clear. His rule `Homesteads` is supposed to be applied to the very first node "Homesteads" which in turns doesn't have a "Users" node and its children, if he wants to apply this rule to the "Users" node then his rule should be called `Users` which by the way besides the variable `auth.uid` that you pointed out is wrong, at the end he should replace `homestead` for `uid` because it seems to me that 'homesteadId' is a pushKey

Comment: @Racu OP is trying to validate that the current user (`auth.uid`) is the owner of the homestead they're trying to read/write (confusingly indicated by `$uid`). The rules look fine to me, aside from the typo I pointed out.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes your solution worked for perfectly for me, silly mistake on my part. I used $uid under "Homesteads" because I mistakenly assumed that $uid was a variable meant to represent any pushKey but I see how it works now. Thanks!

Also I can't seem to mark your answer as "best" or "correct" or whatever. I googled it and it said there should be a clickable checkmark next to the answers but those aren't appearing on my end :S

Comment: Good to hear you got it figured out Paul. I didn't submit my feedback as an answer, since it's really just a simple typo. It's unlikely that anyone in the same situation is going to find your question and thus be helped by having an answer. Hence: I just commented and voted to close as a typo. On the naming: the `$uid` is really just a variable name. So while technically `$uid` works as well as any other name, you can see that that specific name causes confusion. I'd go for `$hid` for homestead ID, or just `$homesteadId` because it's even clearer. :-)